# Dealing with very similar object classes in object detection

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, object-detection

I'm working on an object detection problem using Faster R-CNN. I need to identify two object classes, and they are very similar to one another. Furthermore they are similar to a third type of object which should be considered as background. Also, all three of these objects have a lot of variation within them.

In my particular example the two objects of interest are 1) a statue of a particular named person who appears in many statues, 2) a statue of anyone else

Examples:
[image]

Also, I want to treat living flesh people, or non-humanoid statues as background.

Now here are some interesting results:

[image]

The RPB losses follow the expected trajectory for such a problem, but on the other hand, I really had to have faith and hang in there for the detector losses. They take a while to start decreasing, and I presume it's because there is a relatively sharp trough leading to the the minimum of the loss function with respect to the weights (because the labelled classes are so similar to one another). Miraculously (at least I think so), it does start to kind of work, but not as well as I'd like it to.

My question is as in the title but here are some of my thought processes:

- Does the class similarity spoil the bounding box regression? And then does that spoil the class inference in turn?
- Would it be better to just detect humanoid statues in general, then train a classifier from scratch on the output of that? (I don't know about this one. Maybe the relevant info is already encoded in the detector of the Faster R-CNN and the added bonus is that the Faster R-CNN gets context from outside of the bounding box... unless the bounding box regression is being spoiled by the class ambiguity)